# Intellisense problems in Visual Studio 2010 for Composite C1 CMS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense, c1-cms

Composite C1 is delivered as a Website Project for Visual Studio 2010. I want to use a Web Application Project instead when I develop. So I created a Web Application Project and copied all the files from the Composite Website folder in the zipfile to my project. After I have done this I see that every class file I create in the App_Code folder dosent have intellisense nor the color notations in the classfile. How can I fix this problem?

*** UPDATE, Problem Solved ***
All I had to do was to move my classes from my App_Code folder to another (random) folder in my solution.

Comment: you should answer your own question with the solution and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was to move my classes from my App_Code folder to another (random) folder in my solution.